# install imagemagik using homebrew, shell

Tags: shell, terminal, imagemagick, homebrew

ive been trying to get imagemagik onto my mac using homebrew and the terminal when i run

```
$ brew install imagemagick
```

i get

```
==> Installing imagemagick dependency: pkg-config
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/pkg-config-0.27.1.lion.bottle.tar.gz

curl: (52) Empty reply from server
Error: Download failed: https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/pkg-config-0.27.1.lion.bottle.tar.gz
```

is that just to do with a part of sourge force not responding, or is it an error on my end, ive not seen a "52 empty reply from server" before, is that a similar to a 500 error ?

for the record im running the latest xcode and lion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SourceForge (sf.net) is [currently down](https://twitter.com/sourceforge/status/260742653828812800).

Answer (score 0):

Did you set proxy to access the web?

I installed ImageMagick. First I got the error message:

```
==> Downloading https://downloads.sf.net/project/machomebrew/Bottles/imagemagick-6.8.0-

curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

This reason might be caused by GFW in China. Then I used a sock server and set http_proxy, I got the error message like yours:

```
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

At last I modified #HOME/.curlrc by adding "--socks5 127.0.0.1:1080", and reinstall ImageMagick successfully.